# GPS location information does not seem to be recognised by Lightroom 5.7.1

Tags: lightroom, canon-6d, gps

The gps location info in the image file from my Canon 6D is not read by Lightroom 5.7.1. Is there some setting that needs to be turned on?

Comment: Are you talking about embedded information in the image's EXIF? Or a separate track file?

Comment: I have this same setup (Canon 6D with Lightroom 5.7.1, with camera saving RAW images -- image format was not specified in the question) and see GPS information in Lightroom, presumably thanks to location information embedded in my images. Are you sure GPS is turned on and has acquired your location before shooting photos? If you're shooting JPGs, have you tried examining the EXIF data to ensure that the GPS information is there?

Comment: Hi, I'm shooting raw and the gps info is embedded into that file.

Comment: Do you mean the map tab?  Are you online?  The map is a web service.

Comment: I mean that when I look at the meta/EXIF/etc info inside LR the GPS information is empty, even though it has info when I look at the actual file. @Jakub I would suspect that the Map tab gets automatically updated if these entries had been filled out as expected (?).

Comment: Not sure it's important, but how did you verify that the file contains location information?

Comment: By Explorer - Right click file - Properties - Details - GPS information

Comment: To clarify: you see the location-related fields and lat/long are empty, or you do not see the location fields? If the latter, note that you can choose what fields are visible in the library.

Comment: In LR the location fields are empty, in the .xml-file the lines for datum and such are there, but the lines for latitude and longitude are not. If I manually geotag them using the LR Map-functions, then they appear, both in LR and in the .xml-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During import, under ´metadata` I had checked off  and left the fields blank, meaning LR would overwrite any values present. Uncheking fixed the problem!